# Mapping signal segments to it's signal

Tags: matlab, mapping, hashtable, signal-processing, flags

I have an algorithm which chops the signal based on some parameters and stores it in a structure.

Code:

```
classdef Container < handle
    properties
      segments = struct('signal', {}, 'time', {});
    end
    methods
        function this = addsignal(this, varargin)
            interval = diff(varargin{2});
            [~, locations] = findpeaks(interval,'THRESHOLD',0.7)
            edges = [0; locations; numel(varargin{1})+1];  %note that 0 and one past the end is on purpose
            newsegments = struct('signal', cell(numel(edges)-1, 1), 'time', cell(numel(edges)-1, 1), 'error', []);
            %this loop works for no peaks, 1 peak and more than one peak (because of the 0 and numel+1)
            for edgeidx = 1 : numel(edges) - 1
                newsegments(edgeidx).signal = varargin{1}((edges(edgeidx)+1 : edges(edgeidx+1)-1));
                newsegments(edgeidx).time = varargin{2}(edges(edgeidx)+1 : edges(edgeidx+1)-1);
            end   
            this.segments = [this.segments; newsegments]; %and append structure
    end
```

This is how i call this function:

```
file1 = 'file'
signal1 = file1.yaxis
time1 = file1.xaxis
file" = 'file'
signal2 = file2.yaxis
time2 = file2.xaxis
f = ltifilter.container(); % ltifilter is a package
f.addsignal(signal1,time1);
f.addsignal(signal2,time2);
f.addsignal(signal3,time3);
```

When i call with all signals, `segments` structure will have all the chopped segments of all the signal combined, there is no way of saying which segment belongs to which signal, i want to map the segments to it's parent signal like this:
[image]

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Do you actaully call it with the input 'signal1' and is that the name you want to be stored in the struct?

Comment: yes, something like that.

Comment: edited my code, to show how the signals are imported.

Answer (score 0):

since you want to store additional information you have to add them to the struct like

```
segments = struct('signal', {}, 'time', {}, 'origin', {});
```

if you call the funtion like shown in the code i think it would be best to store the inputname (singal1 for example). depending on how the data is acquired and on how many signals you have it could better to get the filename and/or just the numer ob the signal, but thats up to you. only the input name is quite easy,as there is a matlabfunction for that. just add to the for loop ofy our function :

```
newsegments(edgeidx).origin = inputname(varargin{1})
```

Please note that this works only when you call it like shown above. If you put the data in directly as input the inputname is empty.

Comment: What i wanted to do is, i wanted to fetch all the segments of a given signal, for example i have a signal called `Signal1`. in later stage of my code, for some calculation i want to use the segments of only `Signal1`.  and another part of my code i want to use segments of `Signal2`. How do i go ahead with this problem

Comment: Do you think creating another class just to hold the data is better?

Comment: you could use it like this: when all signals are added try using segments(segments.origin=='signal1') and you get only the part of your struct that has data added from signal1. if this works for you, i wouldnt create another class, but you have to decide what works better in your code

Comment: Thank your for your reply, I totally understadn the concept. I have another problem. Everything should be automatized. The number of signals uploaded is arbitrary and the number of segments its been chopped into is also arbitatry, Is there any way I can figure out total number of signals uploaded(because in my container class, theres no concept of full signals, i only deal with segments) and their segments.

Comment: a few actually. but to figure out the right one you should add a little more of your code where you upload the signals. if they are all uploaded like you showed unique(segments.origin), but then the opload its not really automated

Comment: Yes, upload isn't automated. Thats because signals will be in a mat file and in the mat file there will be 100's of signals. so i do not know how to automate. Coz the signals might be in multiple mat files.

Comment: i feel like this is a little to much to be handled in a comment section. can you adapt your question or post a new one. where you show how you read in the files and everya step of transformation until you call the addsignal function and the class

Comment: Sorry for delayed reponse, this is exactly how i call. 'import' function on the file and user must know which signal. then (segment.origin). I kinda feel this process can not be automated. But i might be wrong, there might be another way to do this process?